# É possível tornar um texto selecionável vindo da propriedade content?

Tags: html, css

Para exemplificar o meu problema surgiu quando tive que adicionar [Entity HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) ao texto para no momento dá renderização ser renderizado como um texto ou seja ter as mesmas funções que um texto normal teria.

Como, por exemplo:

```html
<p>Entity de Aspas simples: &apos;</p>
```

Para renderizar a entity de aspas simples do exemplo acima como texto, eu usei a pseudo-element [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) e a propriedade [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content), assim resultará no "efeito desejado" de exibir o texto `"&apos;"` e não o símbolo de aspas `'`:

```css
.apos::before {
    content: "&apos;";
}
```

```html
<p>Aspas simples: <span class="apos"></span></p>
```

Porém, ao tentar selecionar o texto inserido pela propriedade `content` no desktop ou mobile (no caso estou testando na última versão Google Chrome), ele simplesmente não é selecionável o que acaba criando um efeito estranho como se o texto terminasse antes da entity e o que é entity não é texto:

[image: Texto não selecionável da propriedade content]

Segundo a definição da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Accessibility_concerns)  a propriedade `content` sofre de acessibilidade já que o conteúdo inserido pela propriedade `content` é gerado por CSS o que acaba fazendo com que o conteúdo não esteja incluso no DOM:

<sup>Do inglês:</sup>

> CSS-generated content is not included in the DOM. Because of this, it will not be represented in the accessibility tree and certain assistive technology/browser combinations will not announce it. If the content conveys information that is critical to understanding the page's purpose, it is better to include it in the main document.

<sup>Do português:</sup>

> O conteúdo gerado por CSS não está incluído no DOM . Por causa disso, ele não será representado na árvore de acessibilidade e certas combinações de tecnologia assistiva/navegador não o anunciarão. Se o conteúdo transmitir informações críticas para entender o objetivo da página, é melhor incluí-lo no documento principal.

Isso já demostra o que provavelmente está causando do texto não ser selecionável já tentei usar a propriedade [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), porém ela não tem efeito, por conta, possivelmente do conteúdo da propriedade `content` não ser um "texto".

Por tanto, finalizando teria como torna o texto selecionável? Não propriamente dito, mas sim, usando algum truque de CSS ou algo do tipo para criar alguma cor de fundo no momento da seleção para o usuário saber que aquilo é um texto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta curta, **não é possível**.

O que você pode fazer simplesmente é trocar os pseudo-elementos/classes por algo próprio. Note que via JavaScript você pode obter o valor, mas não poderá obter o valores mais dinâmicos (por exemplo, usando `attr()`), exemplo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-foobar]').forEach((el) => {
    const after = getComputedStyle(el, '::after');
    console.log('data-foobar', after.content);
});
```

```css
[data-foobar]::after {
    display: block;
    content: ' (sample: ' attr(data-foobar) ') ';
}
```

```html
<div data-foobar="exemplo 1"></div>
<div data-foobar="exemplo 2"></div>
```

Vai retornar apenas algo como: `(sample: " attr(data-foobar)`.

No seu caso especifico, se a única intenção é exibir isso `&apos;` **e poder selecionar**, simplesmente combine `&amp;` (que representa o próprio **e comercial**, em inglês *ampersand* ou *and sign*) com parte do *HTML entity* desejado, no caso `&amp;` + `apos;`:

```html
<p>Exemplo: &amp;apos;</p>
```

[image: selecionando amostra de HTML entity]

Exemplos de uso:

| Símbolo | Por nome | Por número | Nome | Uso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| & | &amp; | &#38; | Ampersand | `&amp;amp;` ou `&amp;#38;` |
| ∀ | &forall; | &#8704; | For all | `&amp;forall;` ou `&amp;#8704;` |
| ∂ | &part; | &#8706; | Part | `&amp;part;` ou `&amp;#8706;` |
| ∃ | &exist; | &#8707; | Exist | `&amp;exist;` or `&amp;#8707;` |
| ∅ | &empty; | &#8709; | Empty | `&amp;empty;` ou `&amp;#8709;` |

Comment: Realmente faz mais sentido usar `content` para adicionar conteúdos que não são tão importantes como questões de estilos (que não precisam de acessibilidade) para o conteúdo principal. Valeu pelo último insight, eu não me atentei sobre isso.